# how Insert multiple clob records to oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odp.net, clob

We are working on custom ETL tool. We extract data from database in files, Files may contain clob data. On the loading side, it picks up the file and writes to the database tables. All the files works correctly until the introduction of clob data. The file can contain millions of records. We use OleDb to generate the database schema and make an update using an adapter by reading data in chunks.

My Question is how do we insert clob data into the database. If the file contains millions of records and clob supports upto 4GB of data for each record.

How should we handle these cases and make the application perform faster, and less error prone?

Thanks, Bunny

Comment: If you are going from Oracle to Oracle, look into database links (if databases can 'see' each other) and expdp/impdp (if you want something with a degree of separation).

Comment: Nope its from production to test server. We can't use database links. It has to go through middle tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear.

Is the clob data inline with the other fields that are being loaded?

Does your code work inserting a single clob?

When I extract and load data with clobs or blobs, I keep these as separate files (1 CSV file and one file per clob) and do the load as two steps per record - first insert the non-clob data from the csv file and then update the record inserting the clob.

Comment: Yes we are also doing the same using 2 files. The problem is we are not able to insert data when it contains clob to database. We use DataAdapter and update by passing the dataTable(generated by schema) that contains the actual combined data.

Comment: How are you inserting data from file to database?